# addEventListener doesn't respond in javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

The addEventListener isn't working properly on the "var playbutton" portion. What am I doing wrong?

When I run the playlist.prototype.play function in the console. That code runs but i can't seem to bind it to the HTML button.

```
function mediaPlayer(title, artist){
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;
}

var songOne = new Audio('media/song_1.mp3');
var songTwo = new Audio('media/song_2.mp3');
var songThree = new Audio('media/song_3.mp3');
var songFour = new Audio('media/song_4.mp3');
var songFive = new Audio('media/song_5.mp3');

mediaPlayer.prototype = Object.create(playlist.prototype);

function playlist(){
    this.mediaList = [songOne, songTwo, songThree, songFour, songFive];
    this.nowPlayingIndex = 0;
}

function viewPlaylist(){
    playlist.call(this);
    for(var i = 0; i < mediaList.length; i++){
        console.log(mediaList[i]);
    }
}


playlist.prototype.play = function(){
    var currentMedia = this.mediaList[this.nowPlayingIndex];
    console.log(currentMedia);
    currentMedia.play();

}

var playButton = document.getElementById("playButton");
    playButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    currentMedia.play();
    document.getElementById("nowPlayingSpan").innerHTML = currentMedia;
    document.getElementById("upNextSpan").innerHTML = currentMedia[1];
}) ;

playlist.prototype.pause = function(){
    var currentMedia = this.mediaList[this.nowPlayingIndex];
    currentMedia.pause();
}

var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pauseButton");
    pauseButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    currentMedia.pause();   
}) ;
```

Comment: because `currentMedia` is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Because `cuurrentMedia` is undeclared in `addEventListener` scope, so you should replace `cuurrentMedia` with `playlist.mediaList[playlist.nowPlayingIndex]`

Answer (score 0):

You define currentMedia inside a function and it belongs only to that function(The scope of current media is the function.).

```
playlist.prototype.play = function(){
    *var currentMedia* = this.mediaList[this.nowPlayingIndex];
    console.log(currentMedia);
    currentMedia.play();
```

}

Define it separately as a global variable and assign values inside the function.

```
var currentMedia = {};
playlist.prototype.play = function(){
    currentMedia = this.mediaList[this.nowPlayingIndex];
    console.log(currentMedia);
    currentMedia.play();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Im now getting Uncaught TypeError: currentMedia.play is not a function
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous>

Comment: try currentMedia.get(0).play();